# Should one use local storage to persist and reload redux state and JWT across browser restarts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, oauth-2.0, jwt

Is there any rule regarding when to use local storage or not to store state information if I have redux?

For example if I have some online form, then

**Q1.** should I have its state (currently filled values) persisted to localstorage say when user closes tab or browser, so that I can reload the state in redux from localstorage when user revisits the webpage? Is there any well know / documented security consideration for storing redux state in local storage?

**Q2.** Or should I always send last saved redux state from the server (and not save and load from localstorage) when user visits the website first time after opening the browser. If that is the case

**Q3.** If the answer to Q2 is YES, then what about JWT? Should we store JWT in localstorage avoiding forcing user to re-login?

Comment: I would just put a warning if the user tries to close the tab when the form is not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**

In terms of [OAuth Best Current Practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.1) I would avoid storing anything like this in local storage:

- Credit card numbers
- Passwords
- Access tokens
- Personally identifiable information, eg name, email

Use browser storage for simple data such as the application path before an OAuth redirect, or simple boolean preferences. Prefer session storage over local storage, unless you need settings across multiple browser tabs.

**Q2**

Using the server is safest for anything sensitive, so it is worth investing in an API driven save and load option.

**Q3**

Avoid JWTs in local storage, since there are more attack vectors that could result in stolen data. If you are migrating from this model then start by storing a refresh token in an encrypted HTTP Only `SameSite=strict` cookie, and store access tokens only in memory.

This will enable you to avoid logins on page reloads or when the user opens a new browser tab, and is easy to implement by routing token requests via a utility API. You could then go further to take access tokens out of the browser completely. See the [SPA Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/spa-best-practices/) article for further related details.

Comment: Great clear points!!! Can you elaborate more on **(1)** implement by routing token requests via a utility API  **(2)** You could then go further to take access tokens out of the browser completely"

Comment: It involves a backend for frontend component. It is tricky though, and an architectural change - this [code example](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) shows one way of doing it.

Comment: I have one final question: does browser receive JWT provided by OAuth provider, say Google, or there is usually some authorization server which redirects to google oauth, receives JWT from google oauth, stores, generates new JWT and sends it to the client (instead of directly forwarding Google's JWT)?

Comment: It is best to use your own Authorization Server, so that you can control the tokens issued and other behaviour. Either way though, only an authorization code should be returned to the browser. This can then be exchanged for tokens via a backend component. which can also issue them to cookies.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Q1. If it's non-updating data and you don't need to make request to backend for it. You can use `localstorage`.

Security Issue with localstorage is that user can access it and alter or delete the data. In that case you again need to hit your api for data.

Q2. If the data is updating (eg - posts,likes in blog app). Then you need to make a request to server to fetch the latest data.

Q3. Yes, mostly jwt is stored in localStorage which avoid user to re-login. If the user try to alter the jwt, the backend has methods to check it. read [How jwt works](https://medium.com/@sureshdsk/how-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-works-585c4f076033)

Comment: The concern is more about what if some malicious code updates localstorage state which then gets sent to server and saved? Also, what if malicious code gets hold of the JWT and impersonate authenticated user? Cant this happen?